# Check that the SSL certificate used to connect to the App Store server is an EV certificate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl-certificate, receipt-validation

Apple [suggests here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/StoreKit/IAP_ReceiptValidation/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012484-CH0-SW7) that during receipt validation for In-App Purchase we:

> Check that the SSL certificate used to connect to the App Store server is an EV certificate

How exactly does one do that in Objective-C on iOS?